# Jasminbytecode says it's missing arguments for instruction goto

Tags: bytecode, jasmin

I'm trying to implement branching in my jasmin byte code program but whatever I try I always get a syntax error on the branching. The code should check if the 2 numbers are equal and if true print "true" else jump to the end label and quit program.

I have used the [official jasmin instructions](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/instructions.html) page as example.

Error:

```
test.j:13: Warning - Syntax error.
if_icmpeg L1
             ^
test.j:15: JAS Error: Missing arguments for instruction goto.
L
 ^
test.j: Found 2 errors
```

Jasmin byte code file:

```
.class public test
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 99
.limit locals 99

getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc 5
ldc 3
isub
ldc 7
if_icmpeg L1
goto LE1
L1:
ldc "true"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
LE1:
return
.end method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `if_icmpeq`, not `if_icmpeg`.

On a side note, have you considered trying the [Krakatau assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)? I believe it would give a more useful error message in this situation.

Comment: Thanks that was it, stupid that I didn't see that.
I'm using this for a school project and unfortiontly we have to use the default(?) assembler

Comment: @Sten there is no default assembler in Java. Any assembler is a 3rd party product. The choice for Jasmin is arbitrary and, given that this tool has not been updated for a decade, questionable.